# python mongoening time series collection support

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I was looking for a solution for storage and retrieval of time series data.

As I have mongodb set up already in my project, I searched for a solution with mongodb and mongoengine (instead of pymongo).

So I wonder if there a similar solution to this for mongoengine or if there ain't one, how-to develop it.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("60c0d44894c10494260da31e"),
   "source" : {sensorId: 123, region: "americas"},
   "airPressure" : 99 ,
   "windSpeed" : 22,
   "temp" : { "degreesF": 39,
              "degreesC": 3.8
            },
   "ts" : ISODate("2021-05-20T10:24:51.303Z")
}

db.createCollection("weather", {
  timeseries: {
    timeField: "ts",
    metaField: "source",
    granularity: "minutes"
  },
    expireAfterSeconds: 9000 
});
```

Sample code is taken from [MongoDB's New Time Series Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/) in which the solution by pymongo is described but I wanna do it with mongoengine. Is that possible?

Comment: In a word - yes. If you read the whole page you refereed to, you noticed "these collections look and feel like every other collection in MongoDB". It means time series collections are no different from other collections on protocol level. It's internal optimisation. The only change on python side is an extra parameter to create a collection with this optimisation enabled.  btw, they improved it even more in v5.2:  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongodb-5-2-rapid-release

Comment: I just finished building up a simple and custom schema for my case. I think i can use a list field (actually used EmbeddedDocumentListField) to mimic a timeseries kinda functionality. searched for it but didn't get what I desired at first. thanks btw.

Answer (score 3):

try to create your time-series collections with pymongo like this:

```
import pymongo

connection= pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')
db = connection.<dbName>

db.create_collection('<tsCollectionName>', timeseries={ 'timeField': '<timeField>', 'metaField': '<metaField>', 'granularity': '<granularity>' })
```

you can replace every value between <> with yours

Comment: Please try to add more commentary, thanks Mohammad for the answer.